# Using Laravel and Lumen Together

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, api, lumen

I have built a full SMS panel with Laravel and our users can send and receive SMS through the Panel.

Now we need to create APIs for our users for sending/receiving/delivery SMS through the APIs which really has heavy request/response.I estimated that we have at least ~100-200 request per second through our APIs.

So I decided to use Lumen just for APIs. The Lumen only need to communicate to the DB.

Is it good idea to use Lumen for APIs along Laravel?

Any help would be great appreciated.

Comment: As @Christophvh already pointed out, Lumen is just a lighweight version of Laravel, so to speak. if you already use Laravel there is no need to use Lumen. For building an API however, using only Lumen would be more than enough.

Answer (score 2):

pros: potentially quicker response time (i.e. less operational cost)

cons: higher development/maintenance cost.

Both are highly variable, and depending on your app and dev cost, either can outweigh.

With ~100-200 request per second, the bottleneck is likely to be a database. You can horizontally scale apps, but all of them will end up querying the same db, so you are targeting ~ 5ms total response time from database for all queries within a single API request.